# GlassMapper Datasource and current item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I am using  GetDataSourceItem Method from glass mapper to return my datasource item to the view, I debug the code when the datasource is empty the calloutModel in controller will be null, but from the view, model will not be null, it will have the current item model i am using the following code :

**my controller action :**

```
 public ActionResult Callout()
        {
            // I didn't fill the datasource in the component
            // calloutModel value is coming null.

            var calloutModel= GetDataSourceItem<CalloutModel>();
            return View(calloutModel);
        }
```

**my view**:

```
 @inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<CalloutModel>
 // Model is coming the current item in the view (it should be null)
```

Comment: Is Glass's processor for the mvc.getModel pipeline enabled?

Comment: yes I have it in Glass.Mapper.Sc.config

Comment: did you create model in Sitecore under /sitecore/layout/Models ? You need to assign to the controller rendering on model field.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber controller rendering doesn't required a model, there is no field for model there, only view rendering needs a model and i am using controller rendering

Comment: My fault, I had same issue but with view rendering few month ago.

Comment: It might be the processor that is populating the model and falling back to the context item.  If you aren't using view renderings, you could try disabling the processor.

Comment: Scratch that last comment.  That's not it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is due to the GlassView base class.  That class overrides the InitHelpers method and calls its GetModel method if the model is null.  The GetModel method will fall back to the context item if there is no data source item.

To prevent this, you could change your @inherits directive to an @model CalloutModel and then use the @Html.Glass() helper to get access to the Editable methods and such.

Comment: that is working fine, and i can use editable method, but when i use render image like " @Html.Glass().RenderImage(item, x => x.Image)" i am getting error : "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: RenderImage"

Comment: It is working fine now, you should provide the whole parameters to avoid ambitious issue : @Html.Glass().RenderImage(item, x => x.Image, null, isEditable: true)